# C#: loop through array of numbers and put consecutive numbers in one array, and all other numbers else in other array

Tags: c#, arrays, int, increment

I have an unsorted array of numbers. Most numbers in this array are consecutive (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...) but sometimes there's a number in it that's higher than the rest.

```
int highestNumber = int.MinValue;
int secondHighestNumber = int.MinValue;

int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1207, 7, 8, 9, 1803, 10, 11, , 9000, 9001 };
int counter = 0;

foreach (int number in arr) {
    if (number > highestNumber) {
        secondHighestNumber = highestNumber;
        highestNumber = number;
    }
    else if (number > secondHighestNumber) secondHighestNumber = number;
}
```

When I run the code, it'll tell me 9001 is the highest number and 9000 the second highest. But I want to change it so that I get an array of all the numbers from 1 to 11, with all the consecutive numbers *that only have a difference of one*, and a second array with all the larger numbers: 1207, 1803, 9000 and 9001.
9000 and 9001 shouldn't be in the first array, because the difference between these numbers and the rest is too high. So the end result should look like this:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 1207, 1803, 9000, 9001 };
```

Some background info on what the purpose of this is:
Cient creates articles and each article has an article number that is created by looking up what the highest article number is in the "articles" table so far (e.g. 20), then the number of the new article is that number + 1 (e.g. 21); So an increment per number. However the client wishes to be able to sometimes add articles and input the article number he desires for the article, so let's say for the last article he created he inputted 7000 as article number. If he he then creates another article after that, I have to continue with that list of incrementing numbers. So unless the client changes the value of the next article again, the next new article should have 22 as article number (and not 7001).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on trying to figure this out for a while now.

Comment: Sort it, then start from the beginning.

Comment: @ThomasWeller but then the code would return 9001 as highest and 9000 as second highest.

Comment: `arr.Select(i => i+1).Except(arr).Min()`

Comment: @PetSerAl: That is _really_ clever. Noice.

Comment: How does finding highest and second highest solve the problem?

Comment: Does that list alays start at 1 or not? If 1 is not in the list, should 1 be proposed as the next number?

Comment: What if there are multiple consecutive ranges?  ie {10,11,12, 100,101,102, 500,501,505}

Comment: @Paparazzi originally I used to look up only the highest and second highest but this would become an issue if my clients starts inputting more different article numbers.

Comment: @ThomasWeller list always starts at 1

Comment: @BradleyUffner If there are more consecutive ranges it should increment the lowest range so if it's 10, 11, 12 then the next new article number should be 13.

Comment: @Magali Your two last comments (to Bradley Uffner and to ThomasWeller) do not adds-up together. If it always starts from 1, then answer to { 10, 11, 12, 100, 101, 102, 500, 501, 505 } will be 1, since it is not in the list. If you always increment lowest range (which potentially can include only one number) then you will not always start with 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are just wanting to get the next number you should use or you want the 2 sets.  If you want the two sets, I would do this:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1207, 7, 8, 9, 1803, 10, 11, , 9000, 9001 };
int counter = 0;
List<int> l1 = new List<int>();
List<int> l2 = new List<int>();

foreach (int number in arr) {
    if(l1.Count==0 || l1[l1.Count-1] == (number -1))
        l1.Add(number);
    else
        l2.Add(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1207, 7, 8, 9, 1803, 10, 11, 9000, 9001 };

// Sort the array
Array.Sort(arr);

// Start at the beginning and check if the index matches the actual number.
// Computer begins at 0, so fix that
for (int index=0;index<arr.Length; index++)
{
    if (arr[index] != index+1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Next ID is " +(index+1));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could rework your approach.  Store two numbers for each article, your system-generated number: 1, 2, 3, ... and a client-assigned number (if present).  Use whatever number is appropriate for each situation.